# How can I serialize (with Django REST API) when class relates to the same generic relation multiple times?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, generic-relations

I have a class that has multiple references to the same generic class for different information:

```
class Resort(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('HapNr.'), primary_key=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Kurzzeichen'), max_length=3, blank=True)
    short_description = GenericRelation('MultiLingualText',
                                   verbose_name=_('Beschreibung (ML)'),
                                   related_query_name='resortshortdescriptions')
    long_description = GenericRelation('MultiLingualText',
                                   verbose_name=_('Einleitung (ML)'),
                                   related_query_name='resortlongdescription')

class MultiLingualText(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(hmodels.LanguageCode, verbose_name=_('Sprache'))
    valid_from = models.DateField(_('Gültig ab'), default=timezone.now)
    text = models.TextField(_('Text'))
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('Typ'))
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    atu_id = models.CharField(_('ATU Text Id'), max_length=12, editable=False, blank=True)
    atu_context = models.CharField(_('ATU Kontext'), max_length=1, editable=False, blank=True)
```

When I need to work with this class using the Django Admin I have two Inlines, each with a queryset selecting the correct texts for that relation. This works fine.

I tried doing something similar by using individual serializers and viewsets for each relation, but when I retrieve a resort, it still shows all texts with each relation.

```
class ResortSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    short_description = MultiLingualTextSerializerRSD(many=True, read_only=True)
    long_description = MultiLingualTextSerializerRLD(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Resort

class MultiLingualTextSerializerRSD(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = MultiLingualText

class MultiLingualTextViewSetRSD(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MultiLingualTextSerializerRSD
    queryset = MultiLingualText.objects.exclude(atu_id='').order_by('resort', 'content_type', 'object_id',
                                                                '-valid_from')

class ResortViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Resort.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ResortSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'sihot_nr')
```

So basically my question is, how can I use different querysets for each set of texts? Or is this at all possible?

Correct implementation (Thanks to @lucasnadalutti)

```
class ResortSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    short_description = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    long_description = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_short_description(self, obj):
        qs = MultiLingualText.objects.exclude(atu_id='').order_by('-valid_from', 'language__code')
        return MultiLingualTextSerializer(qs, many=True, read_only=True).data

    def get_long_description(self, obj):
        qs = MultiLingualText.objects.filter(atu_id='').order_by('-valid_from', 'language__code')
        return MultiLingualTextSerializer(qs, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

Comment: Can you show the viewset through which the resort is retrieved?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti: Added the ResortViewSet to the question code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiLingualTextViewSetRSD` does not make much sense in this context, as what you want is to send the resorts *and* their descriptions in one request only, as it should be. In ordinary `ForeignKey` model field relations, I'm pretty sure that `ResortSerializer` would serialize only its related records as you expected, but I'm not sure about how DRF serializers work with generic relations.

That said, one solution would be to replace:

```
short_description = MultiLingualTextSerializerRSD(many=True, read_only=True)
long_description = MultiLingualTextSerializerRLD(many=True, read_only=True)
```

with:

```
short_description = SerializerMethodField()
long_description = SerializerMethodField()
```

And implement your filtering-and-serialization inside `get_short_description` and `get_long_description` methods. Another solution is to remove both attributes and place this logic inside your serializer's `to_representation` method.

Comment: Works! Thanks again!

Added my implementation to the original question to reflect answer.

Comment: For those who want to implement this the `SerializerMethodField()` is read only.